# Inicializar membros de uma estrutura, acessada via ponteiro, no construtor de uma classe C++

Tags: c++, construtor

Imagine a classe `DateTime` da seguinte maneira:

**datetime.hpp:**

```
#ifndef DATETIME_HPP
#define DATETIME_HPP

#include <ctime>

class DateTime {
    public:
        DateTime();
        DateTime(int, int, int, int, int); 

    private:
        std::tm *date;
};
#endif // DATETIME_HPP
```

**datetime.cpp:**

```
#include "datetime.hpp"

DateTime::DateTime() : date(new std::tm)
{
    //date = new std::tm;
    date->tm_sec    = 0;
    date->tm_min    = 0;
    date->tm_hour   = 0;
    date->tm_mday   = 0;
    date->tm_mon    = 0;
    date->tm_year   = 0;
    date->tm_wday   = 0;
    date->tm_yday   = 0;
    date->tm_isdst  = 0;
    date->tm_gmtoff = 0;
    date->tm_zone   = 0;
}

DateTime::DateTime(int _D, int _M, int _Y, int _h, int _m) : date(new std::tm)
{
    date->tm_sec    = 0;
    date->tm_min    = _m;
    date->tm_hour   = _h;
    date->tm_mday   = _D;
    date->tm_mon    = _M;
    date->tm_year   = _Y-1900;
    date->tm_wday   = 0;
    date->tm_yday   = 0;
    date->tm_isdst  = 0;
    date->tm_gmtoff = 0;
    date->tm_zone   = 0;
}
```

O código acima funciona, desde que eu aloque memória na lista do construtor e defina os campos da estrutura no corpo do mesmo.
Eu gostaria de fazer tudo na lista de inicialização do construtor, mas realmente estou com dificuldade em descobrir isso.

Seria algo do tipo:

```
: date(new std::tm), date{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

e:

```
: date(new std::tm), date{0, _m, _h, _D, _M, _Y-1900, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Não construa uma resposta hibrida de inglês e português porque acaba por complicar e tornar a pergunta mais confusa tanto aos falantes de portugues como ingles. Sendo esta a comunidade portuguesa do Stackoverflow o correto é deixar a pergunta apenas com o texto em português. Se quiser pode também fazer a mesma pergunta na versão Inglesa do Stackoverflow com os textos que tem em inglês.

Comment: Cara, acho que agora entendi a tua pergunta, mas acredito que o que desejas fazer não é possível. A lista de inicialização é apenas para inicialização de atributos do objeto, e não serve para "atributos de atributos".

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, é possível, sim, fazendo a inicialização agregada pelo operador `new`, assim: `date(new std::tm{0, _m, _h, _D, _M, _Y-1900, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})`.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Coloca essa solução como resposta

Comment: @MárioFeroldi bom saber! Nunca tinha usado dessa forma. Valeu... Coloca como resposta aí :)

Answer (score 1):

Se `date` é um membro privado da sua classe e seu ciclo de vida sempre acompanha a instância da classe `DateTime`, não vejo a necessidade de se usar alocação dinâmica para inicializa-lo.

Repare que a `struct tm` possui uma dezena de membros, inicializá-la na lista de inicialização do construtor pode degradar a legibilidade do seu código, dificultando o entendimento e a manutenção.

Eu sugiro algo mais legível e menos complexo, sem usar a lista de incializações do construtor da classe, veja só:

**datetime.hpp**:

```
#ifndef DATETIME_HPP
#define DATETIME_HPP

#include <ctime>

class DateTime {
    public:
        DateTime();
        DateTime( int day, int month, int year, int hours, int minutes ); 

    private:
        std::tm m_date;
};
#endif
```

**datetime.cpp**:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

#include "datetime.hpp"

DateTime::DateTime()
{
    std::memset( &m_date, 0, sizeof(m_date) );
}

DateTime::DateTime( int day, int month, int year, int hours, int minutes )
{
    std::memset( &m_date, 0, sizeof(m_date) );

    m_date.tm_min    = minutes;
    m_date.tm_hour   = hours;
    m_date.tm_mday   = day;
    m_date.tm_mon    = month - 1;
    m_date.tm_year   = year - 1900;
}
```

Comment: Eu entendo que aumentaria a complexidade da legibilidade. Ainda assim, se possível, eu gostaria de saber como proceder para fazê-lo. Este código é para motivos de estudos. Assim, acho válido que alguém responda o que foi colocado como dúvida, até para que outros tirem o aprendizado. Em vários locais, se for procurar, você só vê exemplos muito triviais do uso de listas de inicialização. Ninguém dá um exemplo mais pesado, como este, onde se tem um ponteiro pra uma estrutura, dentro de um ponteiro para uma instância de classe. Assim, acho válido continuar aberta a pergunta.

Comment: Vale notar também que é mais eficiente usar uma lista de inicialização do que entupir o corpo do construtor de coisas que poderiam estar na lista, e ainda provocando instanciações que poderiam ser evitadas.